# Typescript Mapped Types, with some attributes optionals

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In a effort to make my Sequelize strongly typed, I'm overriding some super methods.

E.g.

```
type OnlyAttrs<T> = {
    [K in {
        [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown ? never : K;
    }[keyof T]]?: T[K];
};

@Table
export abstract class BaseModel<T> extends Model<T> {

    constructor(values?: OnlyAttrs<T>, options?: BuildOptions) {
        super(values,options);
    }

}
```

This creates a constructor that can only accept the attributes of `M`.

However, some of the fields are required, others have defaults.

In my specification of `OnlyAttrs` I made all fields as optional (the `?` at the end), but I was wondering if TS syntax allowed to do something like this:

```
type OnlyAttrs<T> = {
    [K in {
        [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown ? never : K;
    }[keyof T]] XXXX(T[K] hasAnnotation("default")? (add ?) : none) XXX: T[K];
};
```

Comment: I'd love to see a [mcve] here that could be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/1WGEJN); right now it's missing stuff and I'd have to guess at things I'd rather not.  What governs whether a property has a "default" annotation?  An example would go a long way to help here, I think.